# The saved picture is not the same as the original

Tags: ios, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I use Titanium Studio 3.4.0 and Titanium SDK 3.4.0

Before i use it all is fine.
Now when i save an image i can't read the height and th width.

My code for saved:

```
var newDir = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'logo');
if(!newDir.exists())
    newDir.createDirectory();

var writeLogo  = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(newDir.resolve(), logoName);
writeLogo.write(image);
```

And when i do this

```
alert(Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'logo/'+logoName).read().height);
```

The result is 0.

But when i do this

```
alert(Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'logo/'+logoName).read().mimeType);
```

The result are "image/png" like the original.

Do you know where is my mistake and if there is a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please see below example working fine in iPhone.

```
        var filename = "image.png";

        // Create the file in the application directory
        bgImage = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, filename);

        // Write the image to the new file (image created from camera)
        bgImage.write(image);

        imagePath = Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory + Ti.Filesystem.separator + "image.png";
        alert(ImageViewshow);
        imageView = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
            height : 200,
            width : 200,
            image : imagePath,
        });
```

Thanks and enjoy coding... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily delete the stored files in Titanium file systems be the following code:

```
var file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,filename);

if (file.exists()) {
    file.deleteFile();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the same images as stored, you can put the path as listed below. This is image path where image is stored in titanium file system.

Here is code:

```
// image path: 

Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory + Ti.Filesystem.separator + "image.png" 
imageUpload = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory + Ti.Filesystem.separator + "image.png").read();
```